# make command does not work on MacOS Big Sur - 11.5.2

Tags: c, swift, xcode, macos, makefile

I’m trying an example of using C library in  Swift project.
Below is the reference link

https://medium.com/bumble-tech/bundling-c-library-in-swift-framework-3d9dae950774

C library files link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/giflib/files/

As instructed in the tutorial link, unzip the code and go to folder via terminal and use make command, it does not work.I'm trying to do this on MAC oS Big Sur.
Below is the error

```
**ABC-MacBook-Pro:giflib-5.2.1 abc$ make**

cc -std=gnu99 -fPIC -Wall -Wno-format-truncation -O2 -shared  -Wl,-install_name -Wl,libutil.so.7 -o libutil.so qprintf.o quantize.o getarg.o

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GifErrorString", referenced from:
      _PrintGifError in qprintf.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [libutil.so] Error 1
```

Comment: You are working with version `5.2.1` and article mentions version `5.1.4`. I guess it is little bit obsolete.

Comment: yeah - i downloaded the latest one available as per link

Comment: Please look at your question... does it seem readable, particularly the example?  No?  Then please fix.  Then we can understand what the problem you're seeing is.

Comment: Wow! Censorship at its finest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
USOURCES = qprintf.c quantize.c getarg.c
```

to this

```
USOURCES = qprintf.c quantize.c getarg.c gif_err.c
```

inside `Makefile`. Also, change these lines:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgif.so.$(LIBMAJOR) -o libgif.so $(OBJECTS)
...
...
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-soname -Wl,libutil.so.$(LIBMAJOR) -o libutil.so $(UOBJECTS)
```

to

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-install_name -Wl,libgif.so.$(LIBMAJOR) -o libgif.so $(OBJECTS)
...
...
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-install_name -Wl,libutil.so.$(LIBMAJOR) -o libutil.so $(UOBJECTS)
```

will do the work

```
> make
cc -std=gnu99 -fPIC -Wall -Wno-format-truncation -O2   -c -o dgif_lib.o dgif_lib.c
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-format-truncation' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
...
...
cc -std=gnu99 -fPIC -Wall -Wno-format-truncation -O2    gifwedge.c libgif.a libutil.a  libgif.a -lm -o gifwedge
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-format-truncation' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
1 warning generated.
```

For skipping `xmlto` execution, remove

```
#       $(MAKE) -C doc
```

Comment: this solution worked. @Oo.oO - thanks